# SSO Authentication for Login Failed in JMeter - 401 Response Code

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm doing Jmeter scripting for Login flow which is having SSO authentication.
I have correlated almost all the token values like SAML request, SAML response,Request verification token & client id request ,but I'm not getting proper response in the login call.The SSO calls is failing with 401 response code.

When we try to decode the SAML response(using online SAML decoder) which i'm getting it from the previous request call response in Jmeter, the Status is showing as Responder. but the same is showing as **Success** when we decode the SAML response which we are getting it from the LoadRunner or Developer Console

Note : The same script is working fine in Load Runner

Can Someone help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX0fX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If "the same script is working fine in Load Runner" and doesn't work in JMeter - this is not the same script. You need to figure out what are the differences and amend your JMeter configuration so JMeter will send the same requests as Load Runner (or even better a real browser)

> I have correlated almost all the token values

"almost all" is not sufficient, you need to correlate **all** the dynamic parameters.

Use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the requests originating from JMeter and Load Runner (or real browser).

The requests must be **exactly the same** (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)). Once you send the same request you will get the same response. Pay attention to literally everything: not only request body matters, take a look at [URL query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and so on.